# I've been out of the loop since 2.8. What did I miss?

Tags: loop

I haven't done any serious WP development since version 2.8, although I fiddled a bit with version 3.0.  Short of reading the release notes on each version, what are the major things to take note of as 1) a theme/plugin developer and 2) an administrator?

I've already identified three things:

- Custom Post Types and Taxonomies
- Custom Menus
- Post Formats (a la Tumbr)

What else do I need to take note of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In no particular order, other notable things are:

- old default theme was deprecated in favor of annual theme changes, you jumped over Twenty Ten theme and current one is Twenty Eleven
- WordPress MU was merged into mainline WordPress and is now called multisite feature
- serious improvements to complex querying by taxonomies and custom fields
- server requirements had been bumped to newer versions of PHP and MySQL

There had also been a lot of work done on admin UI and such. Too much of smaller stuff to list, just go through [version pages in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions) (click version numbers, changelog pages are useless).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not so much interested in the smaller things (at this stage, at least), hence the question here. The important stuff tends to be drowned out on version pages.